Error when training on WSL2 that wasn't there on windows
I've been trying to make a simple language model using python and tensorflow and I've found that to propperly use the gpu I'd need to run on WSL, no problem of course. Though a new problem arose. It throws this error: TypeError: Layer.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given which is from this function
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units):
    super().__init__(self)
    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    self.gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(rnn_units,
                                   return_sequences=True,
                                   return_state=True)
    self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)

  def call(self, inputs, states=None, return_state=False, training=False):
    x = inputs
    x = self.embedding(x, training=training)
    if states is None:
      states = self.gru.get_initial_state(x)
    x, states = self.gru(x, initial_state=states, training=training)
    x = self.dense(x, training=training)

    if return_state:
      return x, states
    else:
      return x

If I change the line super().__init__(self) to super().__init__() it solves this problem but creates another, and now it throws this error: {{function_node __wrapped__Pack_N_2_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} Shapes of all inputs must match: values[0].shape = [256,100,256] != values[1].shape = [] [Op:Pack] name:
I was wondering if anyone with more then 20 minutes of TF experience could help me out here.

just checked your code on google cloud. And seems working. Could it be that you have problem with the inputs?
import tensorflow as tf

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, rnn_units):
    super().__init__()
    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    self.gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(rnn_units,
                                   return_sequences=True,
                                   return_state=True)
    
    self.dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)

  def call(self, inputs, states=None, return_state=False, training=False):
    x = inputs


    x = self.embedding(x, training=training)

    if states is None:
      states = self.gru.get_initial_state(x)
      
    x, states = self.gru(x, initial_state=states, training=training)
    x = self.dense(x, training=training)

    if return_state:
      return x, states
    else:
      return x


batch_size = 433
vocab_size = 10000
sentence_length = 40

with tf.device(tf.DeviceSpec(device_type="GPU")):

  tt = tf.random.uniform(shape=(batch_size, sentence_length), minval=0, maxval=vocab_size, dtype=tf.int32)
  model = MyModel(vocab_size = vocab_size,  embedding_dim = 256, rnn_units = 16)     
  ff = model.call(tt)

ff


It could very much be that this problem is fully on me but as i said before, i dont have a lot of experience on TF. I can see that the problem is in the shape of the input(whatever that means). If you need any more code just ask.

Could you please try running my code on your GPU on WSL. If it breaks than I would recommend to check your python libraries. Otherwise it works and this means that the Model code is correct and the problem is in the inputs.
what I would check before proceeding: 1. your python version, 2. your tensorflow version, 3. that both inputs and model are on the same device ('gpu' or 'cpu')

My view that your model code is correct. I think that it is quite decent.
